# Javascript - What is the difference between these constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, constructor

What is the difference between this constructor function:

```
    var Person = function(living, age, gender) {
        this.living = living;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.getGender = function() {return this.gender};
    }
```

and this one:

```
    var Person = function Person(living, age, gender) {
        this.living = living;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.getGender = function() {return this.gender;};
    };
```

Comment: One is an anonymous function, the other is a named function. The named function may be (a tiny bit) easier to debug depending on how you are debugging and with what tools.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing at all, other than the constructor function being "named". For #1, `Person.name` would evaluate to an empty string, and for #2, `Person.name` would evaluate to `"Person"`.

Answer (score -1):

The `name` property will be set in the `function Person(...)`.

You can see this by trying something like

```
var bar = function eigor(){}
```

and then seeing what `bar.name` is.